# Is it possible to disable Opera Auto Refresh Feature via php ?

Tags: php, browser, opera

I have this page which is being used by several users...some use Opera which has a feature where you can set an automatic refresh every period of time...

Is there any way I can detect the browser and disable that feature for the page ?

Comment: Don't think that'd be possible.

Comment: Users with other browsers can have some userscript/plugin that provide same functionality. Why would you event want to disallow refreshing of page?